how to add marker variable into let latlng2
i want to add my start point(letlng2) with my live marker (red car), please help?
function showPosition(position) {
  if (marker) {
    map.removeLayer(marker);
  }
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  lng = position.coords.longitude;
  accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
  marker = L.marker([lat, lng], { icon: icon1 })
    .bindPopup("Lokasi Anda")
    .addTo(map)
    .openPopup();

  let latLng2 = L.latLng(lat, lng);
  let latLng1 = L.latLng(-7.849887646686694, 110.46051951389998);

  setInterval(() => {
    if (routingControl) {
      map.removeLayer(waypoints);
    }
    routingControl = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [latLng2, latLng1],
    }).addTo(map);
  }, 1000);
}



Define your function without the interval. Set the interval outside of the function, and inside the interval: 1) get the position from the navigator.geolocation or with Leaflet.Control.Gps, 2) call your function with that position.
